# VS Code doesn't launch debugger the first time after opening

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging

I created my first TypeScript project in VS Code following the tutorials on the VSCode website. I can transpile my .ts file in a .js file just fine, get autocomplete etc., but if I started the debugger (F5, Node.js installed and selected as a debugger) right after opening VSCode, the debugger doesn't start - the debug console instead says "please start a debug session..". If at this point I stop the debugger (shift F5) then restart it, everything works fine. Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "out",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

and my launch.json:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.ts",
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
        "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am running VSCode 1.76.0.
Anything I might have missed?

Comment: Update - the issue goes away if I remove line "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json", from launch.json. Now I have to transpile manually every time I change the source, though.

Comment: Final update - a colleague rescued me. I had "Extension Pack for Java" enabled - the trace he ran showed that this was getting in the way of the pre-launch build. I disabled it and I am now a happy camper.